# MEF Loading and Unloading specific Plugin?

Tags: c#, winforms, plugins, mef

i'm new in the plugin world and force to unterstood mef. 
Currently i know how i can load plugins from a specific folder.
Now i have some questions:

- Can i load plugins from a folder which are specify in a configuarations file (Serialization) ?
- How i can unload plugins ?
- How can i load plugins with a specific version between min&max version?
- How i can wrap the catalog & compose e.g. as something like "MEF Manager"

optionaly:

- How i can display forms from plugin?

thanks for help

Comment: You really consider this ONE question? Try to prioritize and show some research effort so people can know what to answer to.

Comment: Bad question, but the answer was really handy. I learned a lot, so I threw you an upvote =P.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can i load plugins from a folder which are specify in a
>   configuarations file (Serialization) ?

Yes you can load plugins from folders using MEF's [DirectoryCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx) class. You will have to add you own section in the configuration file though and create a `DirectoryCatalog` for each folder where plugins are located. [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration) contains great information on how to use the classes in the `System.Configuration` namespace.

> How i can unload plugins ?

This depend on wht you mean by unloading a plugin.

- Unloading plugins when an assembly is removed from a folder can be done using the `AllowRecomposition` property of the import attributes of MEF and a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) for each plugin folder to monitor deleted .dll files and call the `DirectoryCatalog.Refresh` method to force an update on the MEF container. Note though that by default you cannot delete assemblies that are loaded by .NET. To overcome this .NET supports [Shadow Copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx). Have a look at the [The Way of MEF](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/06/13/way-of-mef-slides-and-code/) code by Glenn Block. The `PartUpdatesInPlace` is a good example on how to do this.
- Unloading plugins without the filesystem is a different thing. You will have to do this yourself. Usually you will need a plugin manager that can unload plugins at will.

Note though that the loaded assemblies will not be unloaded only the plugins.

> How can i load plugins with a specific version between min&max
>   version?

You can use MEF's [Export Metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata) to add plugin metadata. Then you the [GetExports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833149.aspx) method of the [CompisitionContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.aspx) and check the metadata before accesing the actual plugin. This is standard procedure with MEF-based plugin solutions. Also have a look at the [ExportFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class that was added in MEF2 for a better approach.

> How i can wrap the catalog & compose e.g. as something like "MEF
>   Manager"

Start by a very simple plugin manager class that provides the basics (depend on what you want to do) and build from this.

> How i can display forms from plugin?

You can do it in the same way as you would do it without MEF. For example you can add a form property to your plugin inteface/base class and make each plugin responsible for creating/disposing it.

Before you start doing all this I would advise you to check `Prism` (Composite Application Guidance) and `Smart Client Software Factory`. These are powerful frameworks for WPF and WinForms applications that need great flexibility. If you decide to check them out I think the best way is to play around with samples.

Good luck